# How to access java enum toString() method in jquery?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, enums, tostring

I have a Java Enum class:

```
public enum NciTaskType
{
    PndReviewWoli, // 0
    OspPlanning, // 1
    ;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {

        switch (this)
        {
            case PndReviewWoli:
                return "Pnd Review Woli";
            case OspPlanning:
                return "Osp Planning";

            default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }    
}
```

Now, how to access this `toString()` method from `javascript/jquery`?

I want to show `"Pnd Review Woli"` instead of `"PndReviewWoli"`

**Javascript Code Block:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#woliContainer').jtable({
        //title: 'TT LIST',
        messages: {
            noDataAvailable: 'No Pending Work Orders available!'
        },
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)  
        sorting: true,
        actions: {
            listAction: "/Vela-web-client/nci/getWoliList.htm"
        },
        fields: {
            taskType: {
                title: 'Type',
                width: '10%',
                edit: false,
                display: function (data) {
                    return data.record.taskType;
                }
            },
        }
     });
     $('#woliContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

**HTML Code Block**:

```
<div id="woliContainer"></div>
```

N.B: There is a jquery script for jtable which is not concern here.

Comment: Where do you have the `enum`? Server-side? Client-side?

Comment: In Server side (in java code block)

Comment: Where is your `javascript` and `html`?

Comment: @AshrafPurno: Code block added.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off putting the string descriptor in the enum constructor.

```
public enum NciTaskType {

    PndReviewWoli("Pnd Review Woli"),
    OspPlanning("Osp Planning"),;
    private final String desc;

    private NciTaskType(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

How you access that name in the JavaScript depends a great deal on your architecture.

Comment: I have included my `html` and `javascript` code block. Please any idea how to call `toString()` method?

Comment: @sarwar026 - It depends on how you deliver the `enum` to the javascript on the client side. What technology are you using server-side? JSP? ASP? JSF? HTML? There are dozens of mechanisms - no way to help that way.